# Linear System Solve for given points in matrix of size 3X2

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, linear-algebra

I got a linear system `Z'=A*Z+B` with 3 known points `(x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)` stored in a matrix:

```
Z=[x1 x2 y2 ; y1 y2 y3]
```

I want to find the affine transform

```
A=[a11 a21;a12 a22]  B=[b1,b2]
```

so that I can calculate `Z'`.

How can I find `A` and `B` in MATLAB?
Why do I need exactly 3 points to estimate `A` and `B`?

Comment: Your problem statement is wrong. An affine transform is defined by 6 parameters (not 8) and the matrix A must be 2x2. Also there is insufficient input to determine the coefficients if Z' is not available.

Comment: Sorry for Matrice A ,it was typo.How can be mathematically proved that 3 points are required to solved this?Maybe from the fact that i have 6 uknowns ,and so i need 6 equations to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to solve the system

```
X = AXx x + AXy y + AX
Y = AYx x + AYy y + AY
```

given three pairs of corresponding points `(xi, yi)`, `(Xi, Yi)`.

The equations are actually decoupled and you have to solve two independent 3x3 systems

```
X1 = AXx x1 + AXy y1 + AX
X2 = AXx x2 + AXy y2 + AX
X3 = AXx x3 + AXy y3 + AX

Y1 = AYx x1 + AYy y1 + AY
Y2 = AYx x2 + AYy y2 + AY
Y3 = AYx x3 + AYy y3 + AY
```

This can be done in the standard way; you can also subtract the equations in pairs to eliminate `AX` (`AY`) and solve the resulting 2x2 systems.

```
X1 - X3 = AXx (x1 - x3) + AXy (y1 - y3)
X2 - X3 = AXx (x2 - x3) + AXy (y2 - y3)

Y1 - Y3 = AYx (x1 - x3) + AYy (y1 - y3)
Y2 - Y3 = AYx (x2 - x3) + AYy (y2 - y3)
```

Comment: Dont understand your symbols.U mean i have two independent systems

Comment: Xi=a11*x1+a12*y1+B1 , Yi=a21*(x1+a22*y1+B2 ?But A , B matrices are uknown.How i solve this? As i see this is not possible with( y=a\b)

Comment: @billg AX AY are the components of B.

Comment: I just dont understand how the constants aij 's and B's will be calculated. I dont get it.I know basic on linear systems , as x=a\y-b , etc